# Rails self join has_many returning all unassociated records when foreign key is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've run into an interesting issue here with a reflexive association on a User model.  Given this relationship:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rewards_referrals, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :rewards_referred_by_token, inverse_of: :rewards_referrer, primary_key: :rewards_token, counter_cache: :rewards_referrals_count
  belongs_to :rewards_referrer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :rewards_referred_by_token, inverse_of: :rewards_referrals, primary_key: :rewards_token, counter_cache: :rewards_referrals_count, optional: true
end
```

If I have a user `u` with a `rewards_token` of `nil` and I call `u.rewards_referrals`, I receive all users with a `rewards_referred_by_token` of `nil`, where `nil` is expected instead.

Another example, I have a counter cache for this association.  Even after resetting the count, Users with a nil `rewards_token` have a `rewards_referrals_count` equal to the number of users `User.where(rewards_referred_by_token: nil).count`.

Basically, it seems like Rails is considering `nil` to be a valid foreign key for this relationship, instead of interpreting that as no relationship.  Is this a bug?  Any idea how to fix this?

`u.rewards_referrals` should return nil if `u.rewards_token == nil`

`u.rewards_referrer` returns nil as expected, however.

Thanks

Comment: Can you run the `to_sql` on the `u.reward_referrals` relation that returns unexpectedly, and paste the result?